# Открыть таблицу DataGridView с ComboBox из файла

Tags: c#, datagridview

Есть таблица с учениками, номерами занятий и оценками. (Оценки выставляются из коллекции комбобоксов).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняется это всё таким образом (работает идеально):

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName, false, Encoding.Unicode);
            try
            {
                List<int> col_n = new List<int>();
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    if (col.Visible)
                    {
                        col_n.Add(col.Index);
                    }
                int x = dataGridView1.RowCount;
                if (dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows) x--;

                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < col_n.Count; y++)
                        sw.Write(dataGridView1[col_n[y], i].Value + "\t");
                    sw.Write(" \r\n");
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

            }

        }
    }
```

Но так же открыть этот файл не получается, пробовал разные способы, но ещё очень далек от правильного решения. Как это можно реализовать грамотно? Так же буду рад обоснованным правкам в коде с сохранением файла.

Comment: А это WPF?
Если он, то есть такой подход MVVM, и при его использовании достаточно считать все в модельку и скормить её вьюхе - все работает четко. В вашем случае придется писать парсер и подтыкать значения в контрол: это тоже делается, но дольше и плохо сопровождается.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/846316/How-do-I-read-load-a-text-file-into-my-Datagridvie. Почти такой же вопрос, только на англ.